# Div that hides all the website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since we can't detect if a website is standalone or not in php, I did it in javascript. I wanted to hide all the website with a white div and write a little sentence in it to say to add the app to home screen. (I maked it red while testing).

I tried `<div style="width:100%;height:100%;" ></div>` of course with the body and the html at 100% too; but there was a white space at the right and the bottom of the page. (I think it was for the scroll bar).

Then I set the width and the height to 110% and the overflow of the body and the html to hidden; but it didn't work. (A problem with overflow:hidden in iPhones).

Then I wanted to set the size of my div to the size of the device (with media queries), but when I switch from portrait to landscape, the size keeps the same and the div doesn't expand.

Can someone tell me a way to do this? (Maybe using javascript to change the class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a the div just beneath the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

This will make the div as large as the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these styles:

```
​div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100000;
}​
```

If you need to hide body scrollbars just add

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MJAAU/​

Comment: I will check the other answer as accepted because of the incompatibility of position:fixed for iOS lower than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use position:fixed,  width:100%; & height:100% for that div & make the height & width of html & body 100% to be on safe side. I think this will help you.